# Loop Columns in Recordset

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Please understand this is not how I would have designed this, nor is it the proper way to do something like this.

However, since I was given this task, and have absolutely no way around the way the data is structured, I am tasked with working with what I was given.

I have a table structured as such:

```
ID
UniqueName
DisplayName
Tag1
Tag...
Tag27
```

Yes, I have 27 columns, `Tag1` - `Tag27`

**NOTE:** This cannot be changed due to the data coming from 15 year old software that is not updated, nor is there any chance of it being updated.  (Hence my dilema)

I am getting my resultset utilizing `PDO`'s `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

How can I loop over these `Tag*` columns, and just the `Tag*` columns, without having to type out `rs[$i]['Tag#']` for each individual one, also noting that there may be instances where I could have 14 `Tag` columns` instead of the 27 I state in this example...

**COLUMN CODE:**

```
// prod_opts_value_fields_prefix = "Tag"
foreach ($rs[$i] as $key => $val) {
    if ( strpos ( strtolower ( $key ), strtolower ( $prod_opts_value_fields_prefix ) ) !== false ) {
        $vals .= $val . '|';
        echo $val . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Nothing is getting `echo`'d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a `foreach` over the `rs[$i]` and check if the key contains 'Tag' with `strpos` and go from there.

Alternatively you could use just a `for` loop running on 1 to 27 (or any maximum Tag value) and have an `if` condition checking if `rs[$i]['Tag$N']` (where N is the for loop counting variable) isset, if not break from the loop as that means you've gone through all possible Tags.

The second solution here does have the assumption Tags are always numbered sequentially and in ascending order.

Comment: I have to be doing something wrong.  Can you take a quick look?  Updated the question with the `Column Code`

Comment: Your syntax looks correct, I would assume since your string structure is 'KeyX', 'Key' is being matched on the 0th position which is then being returned by `strpos` as the matched string position. 0 however is equivelent to `FALSE` in php, so your if statement is satisfied on found examples as well as unfound examples. Add a `!== 0` condition before the `!== FALSE` condition and it should work.

Comment: Nevermind.  I'm an idiot who has been staring at this for too long LOL.  I was using the wrong `$rs`

Answer (score 1):

If you need it in multiple places, I'd probably add a setting to a preferences array or a constant that you can easily re-use:

```
const TAG_COLUMNS = [
  'Tag1',
  ...
  'Tag27',
];
```

You can use that wherever you need it to loop over a result set.

Comment: aye, was thinking of doing that too...  I am setting... uh... settings ;)  But was hoping to keep it as more of a "prefix" setting

Comment: @Kevin You probably could, but then someone decides to make some silly change and you'd have to change it all over the place again :-)

Comment: Aye. That's true too.  Kicking myself for taking on this one  lol